# Android change theme on result activity

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I'm trying to change the theme of my app when I return to an activity from a Settings Activity.

Change the theme there and then the app theme should change. Unfortunately it does not do that. When I go back and forth between the Settings and MainActivity nothing happens. I'm not finishing the MainActivity but am finishing the Settings activity.

Main -> Settings, change theme (Theme doesn't change) -> Back to Main (Nothing's changed) -> Settings (Still hasn't changed) -> Main (It changed)

I don't know how to change it right away and I am using the recreate() method but it still doesn't work.

SettingsActivity:

```
    public class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("themeChanger"));
            //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("theming", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String themer = prefs.getString("themeID", "0");
            val = themer;

            Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener pop = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                    String stringValue = o.toString(); //the value set in the strings.xml
                    String preferenceKey = preference.getKey(); //the key set in the actual xml file

                    Log.e("Settings " + preference.getKey(), "Clicked " + o);

                    setThemed();
                    checkValues();

                    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                        // the preference's 'entries' list.
                        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                        int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                        // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                        preference.setSummary(
                                index >= 0
                                        ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                        : null);

                        if(preferenceKey.equalsIgnoreCase("themeChanger")) {
                            //setThemed();
                        }



                        if(!val.equals(stringValue)) {
                            Log.e("Settings2 " + preference.getKey(), "Clicked2 " + o);

                        }



                    } else {
                        // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                        // simple string representation.
                        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };

            findPreference("themeChanger").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(pop);

            pop.onPreferenceChange(findPreference("themeChanger"),
                    PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(findPreference("themeChanger").getContext())
                            .getString(findPreference("themeChanger").getKey(), ""));



        }

public void setThemed() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("theming", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String themer = prefs.getString("themeID", "0");
        setTheme(themer.equals("2") ? R.style.NightTheme1 : R.style.LightTheme);

    }

    private void checkValues() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String themed = sharedPrefs.getString("themeChanger", "0");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("theming", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("themeID", themed);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In our app we do it by the following method:

1. In Main activity, before launching the Settings activity, save the current theme value to `lastTheme` field
2. In Main activity, in onResume, check if `lastTheme` contains a value, if so, check if current theme is different from it.
3. If a theme change was detected call [Activity.recreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) to have the Main activity recreated with the newly selected theme.

**Sample code:**

```
protected void launchSettings() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    lastTheme = prefs.getInt("theme", -1);

    // start settings activity here...
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int selectedTheme = prefs.getInt("theme", -1);
    if ((lastTheme != -1) && (lastTheme != selectedTheme)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "the theme was changed");
        recreate();
    }
    lastTheme = -1;
}
```

Comment: Is the `lastTheme` field an int or theme?

Comment: it doesn't matter, but I think int would be easier to implement

Comment: I tried this and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: maybe your onStart code isn't being called, try onResume instead and add some logs to make sure the code is being called when coming back from settings

Comment: Its still not working. 
`if(lastTheme!=null) {
            if(!getTheme().equals(lastTheme)) {
                Log.e("hello", "Different things" );
            }
        }
`
This should be onResume correct?

Comment: oh, i get it, you're using `Activity.getTheme()`? You should instead check the theme value you saved in sharedPreferences. I'll update the answer

Comment: It's still not working. I feel like something is wrong in my settings activity. I'll update my question and add that. It's my first time working with the settings and I may have screwed something up.

Comment: you usually don't need more then one prefs file, the default one is `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`, but when you call `getSharedPreferences("theming", MODE_PRIVATE)` you're actually creating a new prefs file called `theming.xml` i don't think that necessary

Comment: if you only use the the default prefs file, i think the whole listener code won't be needed

Comment: DAH! It still isn't working. Do you have any links to recent examples of this in practice?

Comment: add some logs to lastTheme and selectedTheme in those functions, and figure out what is not behaving as it should...

Comment: So I ended up using this library called [https://github.com/52inc/Scoops](Scoops). It seems to be doing the job exactly the way I want, without the full customization, unfortunately, that I would've liked.

And I had done that. When coming back from my settings activity, both variables were the same even when I changed the theme.